# How to embed a DataTable widget in a Python Flask Web App

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

Apologies if this question is answered elsewhere on StackOverflow, I did my best to search for an answer before posting this question.

I am working to create a Flask-based web app using Bokeh for data visualization at work. I have had no problem embedding scatter/line plots using bokeh.embed.components and bokeh.plotting.figure.

I would like to display the data which is being used to make the plot in a DataTable widget below the plot. Unfortunately, using components to generate a script and div does not seem to work for widgets. Components also seems to fail when using a column, row, or layout created with bokeh.layouts.

The general layout of my code is a Python file, which contains my Flask app, and an HTML file which contains the layout of my webpage. The general layout of the Python file is below:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.embed import components

app = Flask(__name__)
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y":y}) # Not sure how to provide sample data

@app.route("/")
def index():
    p = figure()
    p.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])

    data_source = ColumnDataSource(df)
    columns = [
        TableColumn(field="field1", title="Field 1"),
        TableColumn(field="field2", title="Field 2"),
        TableColumn(field="field3", title="Field 3"),
    ]

    data_table = DataTable(source=data_source, columns=columns)
    script, div = components(column(p, widgetbox(data_table)))
    return render_template('sample.html', script=script, div=div)
```

The HTML template ("sample.html") would look something like the following:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.0.4.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.0.4.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.0.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
{{ script|safe }}
{{ div|safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

I've elected to use a simple sine wave as the sample data for this code, but in real life I am using an Excel file (pd.read_excel) to test the code before connecting the web app to a database.

In the Python code, if I replace

```py
script, div = components(column(p, widgetbox(data_table))
```

with

```py
script, div = components(p)
```

the code works perfectly. So, that leads me to believe that the problem is with embedding a widget or a layout of plots and widgets. Thanks in advance for any help that you might be able to provide.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's unclear to me what any kind of answer should look like

Comment: I can try to provide such an example. Should I make a new post or just provide in this comment section?

Comment: "Held of posting work code" - I  doubt the contents of the source is going to be enough to reveal sensitive mechanics of the code. Are you able to focus in on a single line of code, or a function block which is problematic? I'm sure that posting either of these things will not give away the intricacies of the code.

Comment: Neither. You can [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: OK I am currently editing and should be done soon. Sorry for the blunder guys

Comment: Edit is completed, I believe that should be a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I realized what was wrong with my original code. Apparently, one needs to link to the CSS and JS for bokeh-tables when using DataTables with components. Below are the relevant link and script tags.

```html
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.0.4.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Adding resources by hand is a bad practice (hence the reason you landed down here having issues ;). It is really much easier to have all required resources added automatically to your template. Use instead **from bokeh.resources import INLINE** then **render_template(resources = INLINE.render())**  and add **{{ resources }}** in your HTML template.

Comment: Tony, I appreciate the advice. I commented out all resources that I added manually and followed your advice with the INLINE.render() call. It worked perfectly except that it turned out that I needed to add {{ resources|safe }} to my HTML template instead of {{ resources }}. I've had to do this with {{ script|safe }} and {{ div|safe }} before.  I realize it is off-topic, but would you be able to explain the functionality of this safe keyword?

Comment: **safe** filter instructs the template engine to skip escaping of the special characters in the text passed to the template engine (in this case **resources**). Apparently the Bokeh **INLINE.render()** returns a text with special characters already escaped.

Answer (score 0):

The code below renders the plot and table correctly for Bokeh v1.0.4

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
from flask import Flask, render_template
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.embed import server_document
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.layouts import column

app = Flask(__name__)
port = 5001

def get_plot(doc):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y":y})  # Not sure how to provide sample data

    def get_plot():
        p = figure()
        p.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
        data_source = ColumnDataSource(df)
        columns = [ TableColumn(field = "field1", title = "Field 1"),
                    TableColumn(field = "field2", title = "Field 2"),
                    TableColumn(field = "field3", title = "Field 3"), ]
        data_table = DataTable(source = data_source, columns = columns)

        return column(p, data_table)

    doc.add_root(get_plot())
    doc.title = "Flask App Plot"

bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(get_plot))

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    script = server_document('http://localhost:5006/bkapp')
    return render_template("index.html", script = script)

def bk_worker():
    server = Server({'/bkapp': bokeh_app}, io_loop = IOLoop(), allow_websocket_origin = ["localhost:{}".format(port)], port = port)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

from threading import Thread
Thread(target = bk_worker).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening single process Flask app with embedded Bokeh application on http://localhost:{}/'.format(port))
    webbrowser.open_new("http://localhost:{}/".format(port))
    app.run(port = port, debug = False)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response Tony. This certainly did the trick and in a far more advanced/efficient way than my original comment.